# How to query a subproperty with NHibernate's criteria api?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I would like to make a query which needs to compare an property's property with some value. For example:

```
... WHERE Identity.Location.Room = "room #1"
```

How can I achieve this with criteria api?

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will perform a query by joining your tables:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Identity))
    .CreateAlias("Location", "l")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("l.Room", "room #1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not use numbers in the alias name.

```
    var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Identity))
    .CreateAlias("Location", "Al")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Al.Room", "room #1"));
```